# How to get POS tagging using Stanford Parser

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford Parser to parse the dependence relations between pair of words, but I also need the tagging of words. However, in the ParseDemo.java, the program only output the Tagging Tree. I need each word's tagging like this:

```
My/PRP$ dog/NN also/RB likes/VBZ eating/VBG bananas/NNS ./.
```

not like this:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog))
    (ADVP (RB also))
    (VP (VBZ likes)
      (S
        (VP (VBG eating)
          (S
            (ADJP (NNS bananas))))))
    (. .)))
```

Who can help me? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're mainly interested in manipulating the tags in a program, and don't need the `TreePrint` functionality, you can just get the tagged words as a List:

```
LexicalizedParser lp =
  LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
Tree parse = lp.apply(Arrays.asList(sent));
List taggedWords = parse.taggedYield();
```

Comment: @ChristopherManning How can this be achieved in python

Answer (score 3):

When running edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser on the command line, you want to use:

```
-outputFormat "wordsAndTags"
```

Programatically, use the [TreePrint](http://tides.umiacs.umd.edu/webtrec/stanfordParser/javadoc/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TreePrint.html) class constructed with formatString="wordsAndTags" and call printTree, like this:

```
TreePrint posPrinter = new TreePrint("wordsAndTags", yourPrintWriter);
posPrinter.printTree(yourLexParser.getBestParse());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] sent = { "This", "is", "an", "easy", "sentence", "." };
List<CoreLabel> rawWords = Sentence.toCoreLabelList(sent);
Tree parse = lp.apply(rawWords);
ArrayList ar=parse.taggedYield();
System.out.println(ar.toString());
```

Comment: what is `lp` here? you missed to explain it.

Comment: @talha06: I guess it's a LexicalizedParser

Comment: Yes, it's a LexicalizedParser.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit outdated so I decided to add my own. So with Stanford Parser version 3.6.0 (maven dependencies):

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
       <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
       <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

---

```
      private static MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(MaxentTagger.DEFAULT_JAR_PATH);
      public String getTaggedString(String someString) {

            String taggedString = tagger.tagString(someString);
            return taggedString;
      }
```

This will return `I_PRP claim_VBP the_DT rights_NNS`
for `'I claim the rights'`

So If you want to detect verbs in a phrase using java and stanford parser you can do this:

```
public boolean containsVerb(String someString) {
        String taggedString = tagger.tagString(someString);
        String[] tokens = taggedString.split(" ");
        for (String tok : tokens){
            String[] taggedTokens = tok.split("_");
            if (taggedTokens[1].startsWith("VB")){
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
}
```